# How to use regex to match a JSON value with jq?

Tags: json, regex, jq

My JSON data:

```
[
  "delivery_1b36940ef75c49a8864d8cb3ea6a3a9f",
  "toPayBtn_10021",
  "item_fdd0772d0dd74dea93033761ca14e781",
  "item_4f1a3f6fd3afdb940be008a0d325f9ad",
  "delivery_d69dc5e9df971c9b2b1736c2231cb4a9",
  "orderTotal_1",
  "address_BILLING#1",
  "delivery_185e36d98d5e4cc1808e59e44df8c71c",
  "voucherInput_1",
  "address_DELIVERY#1",
  "item_864e1a7daf2aa424cbcb2251d55abda9",
  "item_913196f953cbe8cfc2851c8fa9498607"
]
```

I want to match `toPayBtn_10021` but the number after `toPayBtn_` is dynamic, it can be `toPayBtn_10` `toPayBtn_2` `toPayBtn_847` etc...
I have tried

```
jq '.toPayBtn_*'
```

but it doesn't work, how do I fix it ?

Comment: Please follow the http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve guidelines.  What output are you expecting?

Comment: @peak `toPayBtn_10021`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.[] | select( test("^toPayBtn_") )
```